# ls -l -> Sort files by regex

Tags: regex, linux, sorting, sh, ls

I have a directory with log-Files from different applications which are named like:

```
A_B_C.log.20180205125615.bin
A_B_C.log.20180205125616
A_B_C_20180205133700.log
A_B_C_1234_20180205133700.log
D_E_F_G.log.20180205125715.bin
D_E_F_G.log.20180205125716
D_E_F_G_20180205133800.log
D_E_F_G_1234_20180205133800.log
```

The names all contain a timestamp with 14 digits (year, month, day, time).

I would like to print all filenames by "ls -l" and order them by the timestamp in the name.

The newes Files (highest number) should be printet at the end.
If ther are multiple matches for a timestamt, these files should be sorted in alphabetical order.

How can i combine "ls -l" with regex sorting?

Comment: You should use a pipeline with a separate `sort`.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
perl -le 'print for sort { ($a =~ /\d{14}/g)[0] cmp ($b =~ /\d{14}/g)[0]
                           or $a cmp $b } glob "*log*"'
```

See [sort](http://p3rl.org/sort) for details on how to provide custom comparators in Perl.

- `-l` adds final newlines to printed lines
- `\d{14}` matches 14 digits
- matching with the `/g` modifier returns the matching substrings in list context, `[0]` selects the first of them.

Comment: The timestamps are in yyyymmddhhmmss format so you should use a numeric sort on them `<=>`  rather than the string sort `cmp`

Comment: @JGNI: In this case, it makes no difference.

Comment: But it's still a useful habit to get into

Comment: @JGNI: I don't see why. Coming from a regex match, they are strings, so there's no need to convert them to numbers.

Comment: OK It's just something I got into doing when I was playing with dates and times.

Answer (score 1):

This line with gnu sed should help:

```
ls -1|sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{14}).*/\1 &/' f|sort -n|sed 's/^[0-9]* //'
```

Ls cannot do it on its own. The idea is: take the timestamp out, to the head of each line as key, then sort by timestamp, finally remove the inserted timestamp.